# Site Map issue with format in VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, sitemap

```
<siteMapNode url="Customer support.aspx" title="Customer support"  description=""/>
  <siteMapNode url="ProductRegistration.aspx" title="Register products"  description=""/>
  <siteMapNode url="CustomerSurvey.aspx" title="Complete customer survey"  description=""/>
  <siteMapNode url="ContactUs.aspx" title="Contact us"  description=""/>
<siteMapNode url="TechnicianSupport.aspx" title="Technician support"  description=""/>
  <siteMapNode url="CustomerIncidentDisplay.aspx" title="Display customer incidents"  description=""/>
  <siteMapNode url="IncidentUpdate.aspx" title="Update incidents"  description="">
</siteMapNode>

<siteMapNode url="Administration.aspx" title="Administration"  description=""/>
  <siteMapNode url="ProductMaintenance.aspx" title="Maintain products"  description=""/>
  <siteMapNode url="CustomerMaintenance.aspx" title="Maintain customers"  description=""/>
  <siteMapNode url="TechnicianMaintenance.aspx" title="Maintain technicians"  description=""/>
  <siteMapNode url="IncidentCreation.aspx" title="Create incidents"  description=""/>
  <siteMapNode url="TechnicianIncidentSummary.aspx" title="Display techninican incidents"  description=""/>
  <siteMapNode url="IncidentAssignment.aspx" title="Assign incidents"  description=""/>
  <siteMapNode url="IncidentDisplay.aspx" title="Display incidents"  description=""/>
  <siteMapNode url="CustomerDisplay.aspx" title="Display customers"  description=""/>
<siteMapNode url="Map.aspx" title="Site Map"  description="">
</siteMapNode>
```

It doesn't turn out exactly right... When I add a TreeView to my Map.aspx webpage It shows Home as the only Parent Node.  Home should be the main with Customer Support, Technician support, and administration as the next head nodes then all others under that. 
Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Home is the root node that all the other nodes are under.

I've never used the TreeView personally, but when I used a SiteMapDataSource to build a navigation menu, I set `ShowStartingNode="false"` to skip the root node.

Comment: I'm having to use a tree view in my project website i'm creating. I have to have it set up that way.